# Relevance of IPv6 in smaller shops, going forward?

Tags: networking, ipv6

IPv6 has been touted as the next up-and-comming network technology (for some 25 years now...), but it's penetration has been very slow. What do you see in your environment? Is it used internally at your site? Is it being considered? What factors are being weighted for a decision about it's usage?

Comment: What is your question? Server Fault is not for surveys. Briefly, the size of the organization doesn't change the need to at least implement enough to secure things. A rogue router advertisement man in the middling your first hop is negligent.

Comment: It's not being touted as the "next up and coming network technology" as if it's a fad or a trend. It's the replacement for IPv4. It's not a fad or a trend. It is the next thing. It's coming. It's not up for debate whether you'll choose to use it or not. You will use it... probably exclusively... eventually.